# Logic Explanation behind this code- Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logic, inner-classes, hashcode

I have this code written by someone else and I am having hard time to understand it.

It is working fine and generates correct result but I couldn't understand how it works

```
package you;

import clowns.Clown;
import clowns.Volkswagen;

public class You {
static int counter = 0;
static Volkswagen vw = new Volkswagen();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    vw.add(new RecursiveClown());
    vw.done();
}

static class RecursiveClown extends Clown {
    public int hashCode() {
        if (++counter < 20) {
            vw.add(new RecursiveClown());
        }
        return super.hashCode();
    }
}
}
```

couldn't understand that apparently `RecursiveClown` is not being called anywhere neither its `hashcode()` function

then how come it works and add `RecursiveClown` object.

also why it is returning `super.hashCode();`

there is this other class, that was referenced in above code.

```
 package clowns;

 import java.util.HashSet;
 import java.util.Set;

public class Volkswagen {
private static final int CAPACITY = 5;
private Set<Clown> clowns = new HashSet<Clown>();

public synchronized void add(Clown clown) {
    if (clowns.size() >= CAPACITY) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("I'm full");
    } else {
        clowns.add(clown);
    }
}

public synchronized void done() {
    if (clowns.size() == 20) {
        // The goal is to reach this line
        System.out.println("I'm a Volkswagen with 20 clowns!");
    }
}
}
```

output of these two classes are: `I'm a Volkswagen with 20 clowns!`

but whenever I printed

```
clowns.size()
```

in `add()` method of 'Volkswagen' it always return 0 then How come it compares

```
clowns.size() == 20
```

and evaluates it as true?

Answer (score 2):

The explanation why your Volkswagen contains more clowns than its capacity allows is because of the way the clowns are added.

It is essentially within the line

```
clowns.add(clown);
```

in method `Volkswagen.add()`. It first calls `hashCode` of the clown to be added and then adds it to its internal structure. Since `hashCode` recursively calls `Volkswagen.add()` again, at this point the clown was not yet added to the (internal data structure backing) `HashSet`, thus `size()` returns 0.

This way the capacity is not reached at the begin of method `Volkswagen.add()`, but only when exiting this method (because only then clowns are actually added to the `HashSet`).

Answer (score 1):

The `Set<Clowns>` is an `HashSet`, which is itself backed up by a `HashMap`.
So, basically, when you add an object to the `Set<Clowns>`, it will invoke `HashMap.put()`.

`HashMap.put()` call the `hashCode()` method of the provided object.
That's why your object's `hashCode()` method is invoked without explicit call.

Answer (score 1):

The function `HashSet.add` will, as fge mentioned, check the `hashcode` of the object, before it is added, which means that before clown #1 is added, the `Volkswagan.add` function for clown #2 is called.

This follows until there is a 20 deep recursion in the hashcode function, and once that terminates all 20 clowns are added at one go.

Answer (score 0):

The code relies on `HashSet` relying itself on `.hashCode()`.

When an element is inserted into a `HashSet`, this implementation of `Set` determines the uniqueness of the element by first calling `.hashCode()` on the element to add; if and only if the hash code equals another one is `.equals()` considered.

It returns super.hashCode() because this is `Object`'s one: `Clown` does not override it.

Since `RecursiveClown` extends `Clown`, it is possible to add it to a `Set` of `Clown`s. When adding one, `.hashCode()` adds another recursive clown to the Volkswagen, until `counter` reaches 20.